# html table background not showing?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a nested table inside each cell of my outer table.I want to set a background image for one of the cells so I created a specific class called "innerraya" to set the background image for that nested table.However,nothing seems to be changed at all.

**HTML**

```
<td class="luar"> 
        <table class="innerraya"> 
            <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" id="d7">
                        <p id="d7Event"></p>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td style="text-align:right">29</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
```

**CSS**

```
.innerraya
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url("daunketupat.jpg");

}
```

**OUTPUT**

it works now but the whole table is *screwed up*
[image]

The image is there if I used it as a td background or a normal img src but does not work if the whole table background is changed.What is the reason?

Comment: Since your cells appears to have a background color, the table's background is hidden

Comment: Please post an image showing how it looks when image is in td

Comment: I have solved it! Please check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please go the url below, I have created a jsfiddle for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/ew55L41b/

Hope this will help you :)

Also the code is below:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="innerraya">
                <tr>
                    <td>7</td>
                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" id="d7">
                        <p id="d7Event"></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                    <td style="text-align:right">29</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table class="">
                <tr>
                    <td>7</td>
                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" id="d7">
                        <p id="d7Event"></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                    <td style="text-align:right">29</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS---

```
table.innerraya
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    background-image: url("http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/paper.gif");
}
```

Comment: It works but unfortunately for my case it does not work because I have an outer table.I would love to share it but the code is quite lengthy.What do you suggest I od?

Answer (score 0):

**IT IS SOLVED!**

The issue is that inner table layout is not fixed so I had to add this code inside the innerraya class.

```
 table-layout: fixed;
```

The whole code looks like this :

```
    table.innerraya
{
   width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  background-image: url("daunketupat.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;

}
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]